# import or install ndlml in python for fgplvm

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to run an [example](https://github.com/lawrennd/fgplvm/blob/master/python/demGplvmOil1.py) of [FITC aproximation](https://github.com/lawrennd/fgplvm), but when I try to **import ndlml**, python tells:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ndlml'
```

I don't know if it is a package , I also tried

```sh
$ sudo pip install ndlml
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ndlml (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ndlml
```

There is not a file in the [repository](https://github.com/lawrennd/fgplvm) named ndml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent a email to the owner of The project, and he told me that

> That's an older version of software that I think is no longer operational. You should try GPy for running GP-LVM.

https://github.com/SheffieldML/GPy